# is it possible to delete background from google map?

Tags: google-maps

I have created layer that I have put over the google map: 
[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zro3b.jpg)

What I am trying to solve is, how can I remove the rectangle background from google maps? Is it possible? I wasn't able to find it.

My initialize method looks like this, I have set background color to white:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  draggable: true,
  scaleControl: false,
  scrollwheel: false,

 styles: [
{
"featureType": "water",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  { "visibility": "off" }
]
},{
"featureType": "landscape",
"stylers": [
  { "visibility": "off" }
]
},{
"featureType": "road",
"stylers": [
  { "visibility": "off" }
]
},{
"featureType": "administrative",
"stylers": [
  { "visibility": "off" }
]
 },{
"featureType": "poi",
"stylers": [
  { "visibility": "off" }
]
},{
"featureType": "administrative",
"stylers": [
  { "visibility": "off" }
]
},{
"elementType": "labels",
"stylers": [
  { "visibility": "off" }
]
},{
}
]
};

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

Comment: square background??

Comment: @PaulThomasGC
my map is laying on rectangle background... I would like to have just my map cut out so it would be looking nice, without background in the webpage... something like when you have transparent background on png images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do it. Hard to tell without an example set up though.

```
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  backgroundColor: 'hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0)',
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  draggable: true,
  scaleControl: false,
  scrollwheel: false,

  styles: [
    {
    "featureType": "all",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```